# AU6254 generic hub working very slowly - need a driver

Tags: usb, drivers, hub

I have a USB HUB based on an AU6254 chip, but it works extremely slow on Windows 7, less then 1 Mbit/s and pretty slow on Windows XP - I can run a webcam in 2 MP mode, but if I turn it to 5 MP, the connection dies.

The HUB didn't have any drivers with it, and I assume that the "generic hub" drivers that Windows uses are making it slow. Could that be the case? If so, where do I get the right drivers?

Comment: The generic drivers are the drivers.  I very much doubt the generic drivers are the reason the hub is slow.  What product are we talking about exactly?  USB hubs normally do not come with drivers.

Comment: If not the drivers, what do you think might be causing it to crawl on Win7 and pop that "your device could work faster" message, and in the same time work at roughly half-speed on XP ?

Comment: The message in question normally was a compatability message when a USB 2.0 device was plugged into a USB 1.1 port.  You don't define what "pretty slow" is exactly

Comment: I don't have an XP machine by hand, but I assume it could have been some 10-20 mbit/s, so the webcam could run in a 2mp mode, but lost it when turned to 5mp.

>>> when a USB 2.0 device was plugged into a USB 1.1 port. - what do you think it could mean in my case, i.e. when plugged into a win7 machine?

Comment: You don't indicate how you know the USB HUB uses a AU6254.  if you are talking about the ports on the motherboard, any drivers would be supplied by the motherboard manufacture.

Comment: It's written on the chip inside ) here's a pic http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKzFm.png

Comment: What is this chip attached to exactly?  I asked in very very first comment to provide information on the exact product for a very specific reason.

Comment: well, got to admit that we are trying to make our own hub with this chip...